# Set Sequential Non-Identity Numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I am hoping for some advice on the best way to achieve inserting numbers into rows and automatically increasing their sequence. I am using SQL Server 2014 I know there is the sequence object. I've played with temp tables and what not, but I'm just having trouble wrapping my mind around this. Below is the data I'm working with:

```
Table1: OrderList
Column: LineNumber

Table2: WatchList
Column: LineNumber
```

The LineNumber in the OrderList table is automatically generated by another system and results in numbers by 10k. So, 10000,20000,30000.

The data from the orderlist updates into the watchlist table. Then new rows are added, but the LineNumber is not. So in the WatchList table it looks like:

```
Item / LineNumber / xzy
134   10000   blah blah
1432  20000   blah blah blah
433   NULL    blah blah
839   NULL    blah blah
```

What I want to do is run an update to populate 30000 and 40000 into those null fields and I'm honestly not sure the best way to do it.

If you have some advice or a direction on which path would be best to take, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is there an `id` column in `WatchList`?  Something is needed to determine the order required.

Comment: @AaronDietz Hi Aaron, yes, there is an ID Column (PK, int, notnull) is that the element that I'm missing in what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yeah pretty much.  John's answer may work, but it depends on whether or not `ORDER BY item` is sufficient for determining order

Comment: I would be happy to adjust my answer if you provide the ID (desired sequence) AND if this needs to be partitioned in any way (i.e. Customer_Account)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Hi John, thank you so much, I do see this as working... but I have forgotten an aspect... these lines are under an order number. So I only want to update those values that fall under that order number. Would I put the where clause in the sub select with max or under the standard where clause?

Comment: Sorry Only now did I see your full message (it was just my name before) ..  To answer your question, yes or even via a CROSS APPLY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update via a CTE and Row_Number().

The `@YourTable` is just a demonstrative table variable.

Also, the  `over (Order by Item)` was an arbitrary choice.  You could have `over (Order by (Select NULL))` or someother sequence.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (OrderNumber varchar(50),[Item] varchar(50),[LineNumber] int,[xzy] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (2525,134,10000,'blah blah')
,(2525,1432,20000,'blah blah blah')
,(2525,433,NULL,'blah blah')
,(2525,839,NULL,'blah blah')
,(5050,500,70000,'blah blah')
,(5050,600,80000,'blah blah blah')
,(5050,700,NULL,'blah blah')


;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN =10000 * Row_Number() over (Partition By OrderNumber Order by Item) + (Select max(LineNumber) from @YourTable Where OrderNumber=A.OrderNumber)
     From  @YourTable A
     Where LineNumber is null
)
Update cte Set LineNumber = RN

Select * from @YourTable
```

**The Updated Source**

```
OrderNumber Item    LineNumber  xzy
2525        134     10000       blah blah
2525        1432    20000       blah blah blah
2525        433     30000       blah blah
2525        839     40000       blah blah
5050        500     70000       blah blah       --<< Notice New OrderNumber
5050        600     80000       blah blah blah
5050        700     90000       blah blah
```

Comment: looks good, FWIW, the OP has stated in comments there is an ID column that you can potentially use for the `order by`, but it all depends on if the Id order matches his required order.

Comment: @Tanner Thanks, I didn't see that.  I'll make the adjustment